# Functionality of MSHR in GPUs

Tags: caching, gpu, cpu-architecture

In GPUs, per warp thread requests to the same block address are merged together in a coalescer.

The coalesced requests from the warps are then forwarded to L1D cache. If the requests are missed then they are logged into the miss status handling registers (MSHR). The MSHR merges the requests from the different warps to the same block addresses. But this is limited by the available number of slots per entry, which are 8 slots per entry. And there are 32 such entries. The MSHR is implemented in content addressable memory (CAM) like structure.

My question:

What happens when an entry to a block address (say BLKADDR#1) runs out of the slots (all 8 slots are occupied), and a new request comes for the same block address i.e. BLKADDR#1? Is another entry created, or is it stalled since there exist an entry with same block address?

Comment: This appears to be a hardware question, which makes it off-topic here.

Comment: Most likely a stall will occur. Unless the hardware has some kind of dynamic partitioning of the resources (possible but unlikely) the entries number is fixed.

Comment: @njuffa I am sorry about that. Can you please help me move this to CS SE? I would prefer not to delete this but rather move it.

Comment: @algoProg I have never requested a move, so am not familiar with procedure involved (I think it requires a moderator?)